# What happens to homology without cycles?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let X be a topological space and $C_n(X)$ be the singular chain complex. The homology is defined to be $H_n(X)$ = $ ker \partial_n / im \partial_{n+1}$.

What happens if we take $ K_n(X) = C_n(X) / im \partial_{n+1}$ instead?

(The idea comes from comparing the fundamental group to the fundamental groupoid)

Comment: Have you tried to compute such thing, for example? Try and see for yourself what happens.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The question is well-formulated and it's an interesting idea which is motivated by analogy with another, better-known interesting idea. It's certainly not a homework problem.

Comment: It's not invariant under homotopy.

Comment: Neither is the fundamental groupoid.

Answer (score 3):

Write $L_n(X)$ for chains mod cycles. We have a short exact sequence

$$
0 \to H_n(X) \to K_n(X) \to L_n(X) \to 0
$$

On the other hand, $d$ induces an inclusion
$$
0 \to L_n(X) \to C_{n-1}(x),
$$
i.e. $L_n$ is a submodule of a free, so is free, in fact is isomorphic to $B_{n-1}(X).$  Thus our sequence splits (though not naturally in $X$) and
$$
K_n(X) = B_{n-1}(X) \oplus H_n(X).
$$

Comment: Thanks countinghaus. Do you think there's any chance of a 'geometric' interpretation of this? I'm thinking about $H_1(X)$ in particular

Comment: So, this assumes we're computing the $\Bbb{Z}$-homology, yes?